# What can I use instead of strip() to remove \n,\t and white spaces?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, strip

I am using **strip()** to avoid white spaces,\n, and \t in my scraper.
It works fine with selenium but sometimes with scrapy I get
'***AttributeError***':'*'Nonetype' obeject has no attribute 'strip'*

Comment: Using another method isn't going to fix that error. That is telling you whatever you think is a `str` is actually `None`

Answer (score 2):

You get `None` instead of `sting` and you try to use `None.strip()` which doesn't exist - so using any other function can't help you.

You have to use `if/else` to check what get:

```
if result is not None: 
    result = result.strip()
```

or shorter

```
if result: 
    result = result.strip()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can write it also in one line

```
result = result.strip() if result else result
```

but it seems less readable

Eventually you could use `try/except`

```
try:
    result = result.strip()
except AttributeError as ex:
    print('ex:', ex)
```

but it seems even less readable

---

Of course you can put this code in some function

```
def my_strip(value):
    if result: 
        return result.strip()
    return value
```

and then use

```
result = my_strip(result)
```